# Add a new Trusted Location for word 2010 using VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

*Hi*,

Is it possible to add a new Trusted Location for word 2010 using VB.Net?

I want to do the same steps in the below link via code, is that possible ?

http://www.doztech.net/microsoft-office/how-to-add-trusted-locations-in-office-2010/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didnt try this myself but try to write the following registry entry :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Security\Trusted Locations\Location0]
AllowSubFolders (REG_DWORD) = 1
Path (REG_SZ) "**The Path for Your Folder**"
```

Answer (score 0):

Trusted location is in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Security registery key

so you can add with code here